# Start with variation after \position{}

Tags: chess

I have the following tex file that works:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skaknew]{chessfss}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}
\position[w 1]{8/8/1p6/8/k7/3K4/5P2/8}
\chessboard \\
%|\[\ahead f4| some text |Kb5\]|
|Kd4!|
|\[f4| some text |Kb5\]|
\end{document}
```

But this is not what I exactly want. I want to use the line that is now commented out to parse. When I parse it I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FenBoard.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> pos
```

Is it possible what I want, to start with a variation before I made a move? Same thing happens when I use `\newgame` instead of `\position`.

Comment: Imho it is not possible without some extended hacks/correction to the code. The comment code tries to go back one move (\ahead will than to forward again) and this naturally fails. If your position wouldn't start with move 1 one could perhaps fake a previous position, but skak doesn't like a move with number zero. I would print the first comment with \wmove or \movecomment or something like this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for confirming what I already thought. I will start with a fake position and make a 'hidden' move to get the position I need.